# How to remove a specific character from a 2D array only once in Java

Tags: java, arrays, char

I have a char[][] that looks like this:

```
| U | A | E | E | B | I | E | I | D | A |
| U | A | A | U | E | U | T | U | O | Y |
| O | U | U | X | A | S | O | O | U | E |
| O | A | O | U | W | A | O | A | I | U |
| O | U | Y | C | I | X | A | U | W | W |
| A | O | I | I | A | I | U | H | O | U |
| F | X | V | U | G | A | E | I | P | A |
| I | U | M | A | U | O | U | E | B | O |
| T | O | O | E | U | I | I | E | A | I |
| T | A | F | C | M | G | P | Z | O | J |
```

then if I introduce a word (for example: card), i want to change those 4 characters for this one: '·'. The problem I have is that I delete all the 'C', 'A', 'R', 'D' characters of the 2D array, outputing this:

```
| U | · | E | E | B | I | E | I | · | · |
| U | · | · | U | E | U | T | U | O | Y |
| O | U | U | X | · | S | O | O | U | E |
| O | · | O | U | W | · | O | · | I | U |
| O | U | Y | · | I | X | · | U | W | W |
| · | O | I | I | · | I | U | H | O | U |
| F | X | V | U | G | · | E | I | P | · |
| I | U | M | · | U | O | U | E | B | O |
| T | O | O | E | U | I | I | E | · | I |
| T | · | F | · | M | G | P | Z | O | J |
```

I want to output something like this:

```
| U | · | E | E | B | I | E | I | · | A |
| U | A | A | U | E | U | T | U | O | Y |
| O | U | U | X | A | S | O | O | U | E |
| O | A | O | U | W | A | O | A | I | U |
| O | U | Y | · | I | X | A | U | W | W |
| A | O | I | I | A | I | U | H | O | U |
| F | X | V | U | G | A | E | I | P | A |
| I | U | M | A | U | O | U | E | B | O |
| T | O | O | E | U | I | I | E | A | I |
| T | A | F | C | M | G | P | Z | O | J |
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you post sample code please

Comment: show your codes. that will help

Comment: Put the `char`s you want to delete in an `ArrayList` and remove them from the list if you have found and deleted a matching char in your `char[][]`

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried?

Comment: By the way - do you want to replace chars by row or by column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `Character`s you want to delete in an `ArrayList` and remove them from the list if you have found and a matching `char` in your `char[][]`. It's not perfect but to start you can do:

```
ArrayList<Character> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList('C','A','R','D'));
char[][] myArray = new char[/*TODO size*/][/*TODO size*/];

outerloop:
for(int i =0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    for(int j =0; j < myArray[i].length; j++){
        if(myList.contains(myArray[i][j])){
            myList.remove(myArray[i][j]);
            myArray[i][j] = '.';
            if(myList.isEmpty()){
                break outerloop;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Simpler and more conventional: `myList.isEmpty()`. But it’s a little detail.

Comment: Thank you Jérôme.